# Unable to make product In Stock In Magento2 Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

We are using Magento2.3.5-p1 version , We imported all our catalog of 5000+ products and those all are showing finely in front end. When ever we go to Magento Admin Catalog and select any one of the product to edit and make change of your attributes and click on save then product is going to out of stock immediately.

Step 1 : Verified Stock Status of that product in admin panel , It is showing as Out of stock in Advanced Inventory section.

Step 2 : When i tried to select "in stock" value the dropdown is unselectable . It is still showing as Out of Stock, It is not for one product for every product it is same.

Step 3 : I thought that there is issue with my CSV file , So i tried to create a simple product on my own by clicking on Add new simple product from admin. In this case as well In Stock Dropdown value still inaccessible.

Step 4 : When i give Qty greater than 0 it should automatically change status as in stock in magento2 but not happened.

Any solution for this? Please find the attached screenshot of the issue
[image]

Comment: i am facing similar issue with simple products not with configurable.